# How to put password on apk?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

[image]

I want to modify an apk and put password to it before they can use or install the app.

I really have 0 knowledge when it comes to coding...

Is this possible?

Can someone help me on this matter?

Comment: You may consider to setup an alpha or beta test on play store. The effect is similar: you can control who is able to install the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 0 coding knowledge, I don't think that there is any tool that can help you.
Now, with some coding skills, there are two things you can do:

- If you have the app source code you can write an activity that ask you for a password in order to load the app main activity.
- If you don't have the app source code, with some smali coding skills, you can use apktool to disassemble your apk and then inject an activity that ask you for a password. **This is MUCH HARDER compared to the 1st option**.

Please remember that any **local** password check can be reverse engineered and bypassed.

Otherwise, as said by others, since apk files are just rar archives, you can use winrar to add a password, but I'm almost sure that the installation process will fail.

Comment: Hi thanks. I have apk editor pro. And i like your 2nd option about that source code and smali.

Comment: Apk editor pro is useless for what you want to achieve. Please learn some smali and use apktool.

Comment: Luca can you help me or just provide me the steps on how to do it. Im using apk editor pro. I just need the steps and i will figure it out myself i just dont know where to start after i open the app. Thats why...

Comment: It is not an easy task, you need to learn some smali as I said before. There are no step by step guide. Start by making a simple android app, then use apktool on it and study the disassembled smali code. It is not easy I know, but with time and patience you will be able to mod any apk.

Comment: Is there an app that can change the device id of an apk? Here is an example i want to make sure that the apk i created or modded, cannot be used or run by other device. I just dont want others to use it. I want to put my phone device id on the apk i created.

I tried apk editor but i cannot find where to put my phone device id.

Comment: Again, this can be done by injecting a check inside the smali code to get the device ID and check it. Be aware that this can easily by cracked by any reverse engineer with some basic smali knowledge. Also, plese mark my answer as "Accepted" if you think I helped you.

Comment: Where in smali code can i find and put my phone device id? What is the name of the file or the string where i can put it?

Comment: Mate, as I told you many times , doing such mods require some knowledge. I can't just tell you "where" you have to inject the code, because this is very case-specific. Every smali file name is very specific for every application you are reversing. You should really need to learn some smali, or if you really need this to be done, I can do it for $$$. But be aware, if this is something illegal like cracking paid apps or hacking iap, I'll NOT help you.

Answer (score 0):

**No there is no way to achieve this directly on the apk file**, but if you want to do so you can use compression tools(ex:winrar) and put password on that. BUT by doing so **you wont be able to distribute your app to the world with the help of play store** as you need to upload your apk file directly there.

Comment: I uploaded a picture of an app where the modder was able to add a username and password before someonw can use it. I just want to know how did the modder do that?

Comment: that's a login form... and the modder probably injected a view to do that. Please read my answer for more details.

Comment: thats once the app is installed not before installation

Comment: Yep i have the apk installed on my phone. And i use apk editor pro. I just dont know where to start or what file to edit to add password or username on a specific apk :)

Comment: its not on an apk its after you install that apk that you can do that